# Как отобразить ссылку из view в шаблоне Django?

Tags: django

Где найти инфу как скидывать ссылки {% url 'name' %}в шаблон из view?
Нужно при создании статьи в админ панель в тег "а" добавлялась ссылка на страницу с идентичной тематикой.
Я так понимаю надо модель писать, а что если страниц много(нужен выбор)?
Кто то сталкивался?
вью

```
class BlogArticles(ListView):  # Главная страница 
model = BlogNewArticles
template_name = "blog/blog.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(BlogArticles, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['blockheader'] = BlogPromoHeader.objects.all()  # Реклама шапка
    context['blockcenter'] = BlogPromoCentre.objects.all()  # Реклама центр1
    context['blockfooter'] = BlogPromoFooter.objects.all()  # Реклама подвал
    return contextвведите сюда код
```

html

```html
{% for post in object_list %}
<div class="blog vertical-blog col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="blog-foto"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="/media/{{ post.article_image_field }}"></a></div>
<div class="blog-date">{{ post.article_datetime }}</div>
div class="blog-subtitle"><a href="">{{ post.article_razdel }}</a></div>
<div class="blog-title"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.article_title }}</a></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код модели и постарайтесь объяснить более подробно, что и куда вы хотите добавить. Пока совсем не ясно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос такой на главной странице микс блоков из разных тематик. У каждой тематики есть раздел. Циклом добавляю статьи на главную страницу и в блоке статьи есть код

```html
<a href="">{{ post.article_razdel }}</a></div>
```

вот в этот

```html
<a href="">
```

нужно чтобы попадал ссылка циклом

```html
{% url 'нужная страница' %}
```

но попадала из админки. То есть создал человек статью она попала на главную страницу, а пользователь нажал на блоке и перешел к статьям по тематике. Голову сломал как эту ссылку в модель поместить. И в документации не слова не нашел.